# Missing pgnuplot

Tags: python, cygwin, gnuplot

I'm trying to use gnuplot.py through cygwin, but it looks like I need to install pgnuplot (I get "/bin/sh: pgnuplot.exe: command not found" trying to run the demo.py file).

The README provides an ftp link, but either its outdated or I don't think I understand how to use it. Could someone provide a way to easily install pgnuplot.exe? I've tried searching this, but couldn't decipher anything I found.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't necessarily a definite answer, more like a random stab in the dark -- BUT, what happens if in `gp.py`, you comment out the lines:

```
elif sys.platform == 'cygwin':
    from gp_cygwin import GnuplotOpts, GnuplotProcess, test_persist
```

(You'll need to do `python setup.py install` again)

Now you should fall through to the 'unix' block.  In my experience, cygwin is close enough to unix for a lot of things to work...

Of course, I have my own gnuplot-python interface (pyGnuplot) which you can try too if you want, although it isn't as popular or well documented as the older version.

Answer (score -1):

I think pgnuplot is deprecated. You could simply make a copy of the gnuplot binary and name it pgnuplot. Or make a symbolic link in cygwin. My cygwin has gnuplot in:

"C:\unix\bin\gnuplot-base.exe"

the gnuplot command seems to be a symbolic link already.

[github reference](https://github.com/CEA-LIST/N2D2/issues/17)

"pgnuplot.exe was needed in old versions of gnuplot, but has been deprecated since at least gnuplot 4.5 and removed entirely in gnuplot 5.0."

Comment: I noticed a negative review here without a reason. Please note by example: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/octave-maintainers/2009-10/msg00033.html

Comment: Also, from gnuplot doc "* gnuplot.exe: Text (console) mode version of the gnuplot executable with full
  pipe functionality. In contrast to
  wgnuplot.exe, this program can also accept commands on stdin (standard input)
  and print messages on stdout (standard output). It replaces pgnuplot.exe and
  is recommended to be used with 3rd party applications using gnuplot as graph
  engine, like e.g. Octave (www.octave.org)."